# Print output to console when using KafkaStream Processor API

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When using StreamDSL, I can call `.print(Printed.toConsole())` to see the output in the console.

Is there sth similar when using the Processor API? I expect a `PrintToConsoleProcessor`, or?

For sure I can create a dummy processor, but a `PrintToConsoleProcessor` would be very useful.

Comment: There is nothing like this in the Processor API. Be design, the Processor API does not predefine any operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok could be fairly easy

```java
topology.addProcessor("console", () -> new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void init(ProcessorContext context) {

            }

            @Override
            public void process(Object key, Object value) {
                System.out.println(value.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void punctuate(long timestamp) {

            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }
        }, "PARENT")
```